# Why are there 2 libpq folders in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, libpq

In the `PostgreSQL` source code there are 2 `libpq` folders :

- `src/interfaces/libpq`
- `src/backend/libpq`

What is the difference between them?

As from what I have seen only the one present in interfaces folder is compiled and referred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One's for backend (for the server to receive connections -- `src/backend/libpq`) and one's for frontend (for clients to make connections to the server -- `src/interfaces/libpq`)

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)

Answer (score 1):

`src/interfaces/libpq` contains the code for the `libpq` client shared library.

`src/backend/libpq` contains the server-side implementation of the [frontend/backend protocol](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol.html).